# Manager node stuck in preparing state for service

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-machine, boot2docker, docker-swarm-mode

I have a swarm of 3 managers, 3 workers as below:

```
    ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS      ENGINE VERSION
ocnuul8dcbrf4gjtdzv06t0yf *   manager1            Ready               Active              Leader              18.06.0-ce
z297dhtfon50pt4hllu4qfz6i     manager2            Ready               Active              Reachable           18.06.0-ce
ondpdzyq06pd3oysn34p4xi9o     manager3            Ready               Active              Reachable           18.06.0-ce
0bls0g65gee1wbv7wr6rwgbjk     worker1             Ready               Active                                  18.06.0-ce
mxtg28slr5rvljrayaf4k1wkk     worker2             Ready               Active                                  18.06.0-ce
hqu1436bvbar9srbr34er3fl4     worker3             Ready               Active                                  18.06.0-ce
```

All managers are available.

However, when i deploy a service on the swarm, manager3 is stuck in preparing state

```
ID                  NAME                IMAGE                                       NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE              ERROR               PORTS
lmhpsgeqax13        web-fe.1            nigelpoulton/pluralsight-docker-ci:latest   worker1             Running             Running 19 minutes ago
nivas3gkh0pa        web-fe.2            nigelpoulton/pluralsight-docker-ci:latest   worker3             Running             Running 19 minutes ago
5plwh46jri3t        web-fe.3            nigelpoulton/pluralsight-docker-ci:latest   worker2             Running             Running 19 minutes ago
l1ykqzgzbgmb        web-fe.4            nigelpoulton/pluralsight-docker-ci:latest   manager2            Running             Running 19 minutes ago
q788hrm6rba9        web-fe.5            nigelpoulton/pluralsight-docker-ci:latest   manager3            Running             Preparing 21 minutes ago
```

I could see in the /var/log/docker.log for manager3 that its failing while trying to establish connection with manager2's IP(192.168.99.105:2377)

```
7T00:10:54.230023789Z" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {192.168.99.105:2377 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = \"transport: Err7T00:10:54.230049538Z" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420a86940, TRANSIENT_FAILURE" module=grpc
```

Since manager1 is the leader , i was expecting it to send the message/signal to manager1 on preparing, but i dont understand why its trying to connect to manager2.
Could some one help me understand? Also, how do i recover from this and move manager3 from preparing to running state?

Regards